# Purpose of outer housing in a 3 axis gimbal gyro

Tags: experimental-physics, rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes

In this video [Inertial Guidance System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekzwbt3hu2k&t=86s&ab_channel=ZymplecticZymplectic) Professor Lewis shows how inertial inertial guidance system works. The setup consist of a 3 axis gimbal gyro.

Let $z$ be an axis pointing up , $x$ be an axis pointing out of the page and $y$ and axis pointing to right.
In the gyro there is two outer housing a yellow and a black and in the inner part we  have a red housing and wheel.

Professor Lewis does not explain clearly  what is the purpose of the outer housing but I am supposing that the black housing prevents the wheel from rotating in the $z$ axis and the yellow prevents the wheel from rotating in the $y$ axis.

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

In a 3 dimension space (like the Newtonian space), an object can move along three independent axes (a point has 3 parameters; a position has 3 components).

In the same way, the general expression of a rotation also needs 3 parameters, 3 angles (along the 3 aforementioned axes).

[image]

In the experiment you are referring to, if one the rotating frames (which allow for 3 indépendant rotations around 3 complementary axis) was missing, the gyroscope’s disk couldn’t rotate freely, it would be constrained (one of the 3 angles would be fixed).

Comment: what is the purpose of the yellow housing?

Comment: The three frames (and asssciated axes) allow the device to rotate freely around the three independent, perpendicular, axes $x, y, z$, the yellow frame is one of said set of three frames.